# nginx url rewrite based off path

Tags: nginx

I'm currently using openshift to host multiple apps and I want to be able to handle all the routing with nginx. Say I have the domain `https://project.us.company.com` and the apps on openshift are like this:

```
https://foo-v1-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com
https://foo-v2-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com
```

I want to be able to do a `reverse proxy` and rewrite like this:

```
https://project.us.company.com/foo/v1/test         -> https://foo-v1-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com/test
https://project.us.company.com/foo/v2/test1        -> https://foo-v2-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com/test1
https://project.us.company.com/bar/v1/test?limit=5 -> https://bar-v1-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com/test?limit=5 
https://project.us.company.com/bar/v2/test/test2   -> https://bar-v2-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com/test/test2
```

I also need some logic to make it work like this:

```
https://project.us.company.com/bar/test --> https://bar-v2-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com/test
```

So without a version it should default to a value (`v2` in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Assuming only three apps for now: foo, bar, baz

location ~ ^/((?:foo|bar|baz)(?:/v[0-9]+)?)$ {
    return 301 /$1/;
}

rewrite ^/(foo|bar|baz)/((?:[^v].*|v[^_0-9].*|v[0-9]+(?:[^/0-9].*)?|v_(?:[^/].*)?)?)$ /$1/v_/$2;

# different default versions
rewrite /foo/v_/(.*) /foo/v2/$1 last;
rewrite /bar/v_/(.*) /bar/v4/$1 last;
rewrite /baz/v_/(.*) /baz/v8/$1 last;

location ~ /(foo|bar|baz)/(v[0-9]+)(/.*) {
    proxy_pass https://$1-$2-project.eocp-apps.us.company.com$3
}
```

Comment: yup this works thank you! Only thing that didn't work was the edge cases if you did `/foo/v` or `/foo/v_`. I also added `$is_args$args` to pass though the query params if needed.

Comment: What happened in those edge cases... oh, wait. Right. Okay, I can fix those edge cases.